# bootstrap-table checkboxes are checked on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) and i am trying to set up checkboxes, the problem is that the checkboxes are initiated as checked for no particular reason

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
      <title>Bootstrap Table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">why checked?</div>

        <div class="panel-body">
          <table data-row-style="rowStyle" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true">
            <thead>
              <th data-field="dd" data-checkbox="true">
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                x
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                y
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                z
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                t
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                r
              </th>
              <th data-sortable="true">
                m
              </th>
              <th></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td> 1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td> 4</td>
                <td> 5</td>
                <td><span class="label label-default">xxx</span></td>
                <td>
                  <div class="form-inline text-right">
                    <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}/edit" method="post">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}" method="post">
                      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/12160/

Second question, how do i add a name and a value to the checkboxes, i have tried to return a value/custom attribute from a `data-formatter` function but didn't see any alteration in the dev tool

The documentation doesn't mention any attribute/function/event to customise thouse checkboxes

**Update**
it seems that if you want to sort the selected elements the first column (checkbox column) disappears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually quite funny to see the bootstrap-table breaking down when it finds whitespace character in your table cells. Once they are trimmed of any whitespace characters including line breaks, the problems seem resolved on their own.

```js
function check() {
  $("tbody input:checked").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).parents("tr:first").data("val"));
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">why checked?</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <button onclick="check()">Check Values</button>
            <table data-row-style="rowStyle" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true">
              <thead>
                <th data-field="dd" data-checkbox="true">
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  x
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  y
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  z
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  t
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  r
                </th>
                <th data-sortable="true">
                  m
                </th>
                <th></th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr data-val="100">
                  <td></td>
                  <td>100</td>
                  <td>200</td>
                  <td>300</td>
                  <td>400</td>
                  <td>500</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-default">xxx</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="form-inline text-right">
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}/edit" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                      </form>
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}" method="post">
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-val="200">
                  <td></td>
                  <td>200</td>
                  <td>200</td>
                  <td>300</td>
                  <td>400</td>
                  <td>500</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-default">xxx</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="form-inline text-right">
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}/edit" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                      </form>
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}" method="post">
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-val="300">
                  <td></td>
                  <td>300</td>
                  <td>200</td>
                  <td>300</td>
                  <td>400</td>
                  <td>500</td>
                  <td><span class="label label-default">xxx</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="form-inline text-right">
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}/edit" method="post">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>
                      </form>
                      <form class="form-group" action="{{url('invobj')}}/{{$obj->id}}" method="post">
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have added data-val in each row and function `check()` will log the values of selected rows.

Comment: i don't need indexes i need checkbox values, not row index, right now these checkboxses aren't doing what they are suppose to do that is to send data from the client to the server

Comment: @madalinivascu I have updated the snippet to show the values of selected row. select any checkboxes and click the button before table to see the values of the selected rows.

Comment: so to wrap this up i will need a hidden input field to gather all the custom attribute values and use that as input for my form

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (uncheck all pages):

```js
<script>
        var $table = $('#search-result');

        $(function () {
              $table.bootstrapTable('togglePagination').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll').bootstrapTable('togglePagination')
        });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but I came across this same issue and the answers above didn't help.  I finally figured out my issue, so wanted to post it here in case anyone else finds this issue through a google search (or on the off chance you're still looking for the answer and just clearing the checkboxes using jquery)

For your code above, your checkbox field also links to a data-field.

```
<th data-field="dd" data-checkbox="true">
</th>
```

If the data you fill in later has a value for the `dd` column, this will set as true according to [the documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/column-options/#checkbox):

> If a value is given the Checkbox is automatically checked. Its also possible to check/uncheck the checkbox by use an formatter (return true to check, return false to uncheck).

***So just removing `data-field="dd"` may fix the issue.***

This changed at some point through the different versions of bootstrap-table.  I had upgraded from 1.9.0 to 1.18.3, so I'm not sure when exactly, but removing the `data-field` attribute from the `<th>` that had the `data-checkbox` attribute fixed my issue and it no longer marked it as checked on page load.