# All checkboxes are checked on page load in bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table and data is loading from URL. In the table I have setup checkboxes for ID column. My problem is that the all checkboxes are checked when the page is load. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626413/bootstrap-table-checkboxes-are-checked-on-page-load) here, but its not help me to fix my issue.

This is my JS:

```
var $_bsTable = $('#table')
$_bsTable.bootstrapTable({
  toggle: "table",
  url: "./includes/view_suppliers.inc.php",
  
  columns: [{
      field: 'sid',
      checkbox: true,
      printIgnore: true,
      //width: 64
    },
    {
      field: 'image',
      title: 'Image',
      sortable: false,
      align: 'center'
    },            
    {
      field: 'name',
      title: 'Supplier Name',
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      field: 'address',
      title: 'Address',
      sortable: true
    }
  ],

  icons: {
    columns: 'fa-th-list text-orange-d1',
    detailOpen: 'fa-plus text-blue',
    detailClose: 'fa-minus text-blue',
    export: 'fa-download text-blue',
    print: 'fa-print text-purple-d1',
    fullscreen: 'fa fa-expand',
    search: 'fa-search text-blue'
  },

  toolbar: "#table-toolbar",
  theadClasses: "bgc-white text-grey text-uppercase text-80",
  
  //clickToSelect: true,
  checkboxHeader: true,

  search: true,
  searchAlign: "left",
  //showSearchButton: true,
  sortable: true,
  //detailView: true,
  //detailFormatter: "detailFormatter",

  pagination: true,
  sidePagination: 'client',
  // serverSort: false,
  paginationLoop: false,

  showExport: true,
  showPrint: true,
  showColumns: true,
  showFullscreen: true,

  mobileResponsive: true,
  //checkOnInit: true,
})
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: You need them to be unchecked ?

Comment: @Swati yes, unchecked when page is load

Comment: Use : `$(".bs-checkbox input").prop("checked",false)` after intializing your boostrap table .Working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/g27b1vyp/)

Comment: @Swati yes I its working with HTML data. but not with server side data

Comment: @Swati You can check this example : `https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/welcomes/from-url.html` by adding `data-checkbox="true"` to `id` column. You can see the problem there.

Comment: If you remove `data-field="id"`and keep only `data-checkbox="true"` its working fine.

Comment: Yes in that way its working... but I need to have both fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232815/discussion-between-user3733831-and-swati).

Answer (score -2):

Are you maybe giving a value to checkboxes in your HTML?
From official documentation:

> If a value is given the Checkbox is automatically checked. Its also possible to check/uncheck the checkbox by use an formatter (return true to check, return false to uncheck).

Here you can see an example: https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#column-options/checkbox.html

Comment: I didn't create any HTML for checkboxes. Its dynamically populating by JS. This is my HTML for all about `<table class="table " id="table"><!-- table --> </table>`